# Magento 1 to Magento 2 Migration error

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

For Migration I ran below 2 commands.

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings -r -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.8/config.xml

php bin/magento migrate:data -r -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.8/config.xml
```

Then I got below error

```
[2018-11-15 06:58:27][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: customer_eav_attribute. Fields: is_used_for_customer_segment
```

Then I placed below code in `map.xml` first, then in `map-eav.xml` finally in `map-customer.xml`.

```
<ignore>   <field>customer_eav_attribute.is_used_for_customer_segment</field>
</ignore>
```

But I am still getting the previous error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was mentioned [here](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/595)

Use this [commit](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/commit/13728b3d6872ac3f12f07efccf04f28060b9fbec) for fixing

Comment: Thanks @Tuyen Nguyen. How can I use that commit ?

Comment: @abuabu Download the patch to the local https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/commit/13728b3d6872ac3f12f07efccf04f28060b9fbec.patch

And follow this instruction to apply to vendor using this tutorial https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005484154-Create-a-patch-for-a-Magento-2-Composer-installation-from-a-GitHub-commit

Otherwise you could add these changes directly to `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/`

Comment: Thanks @ Tuyen Nguyen. Finally it solved.